# The working of model.insertNodeInto() function

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I have a little confusion:
Is the function insertNodeInto used to inserts only a single node and not its sub nodes?
for example I have a code snippet as follows:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("topMost");
newNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("A node"));
newNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("B node"));
model.insertNodeInto(newNode,rootNode,0);
```

So will the above code add all the 3 nodes to the tree or just the topMost node?

Comment: Try it and let us know the results.

Comment: Yeah it actually inserts the node with all its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node, with all its children, is inserted in the model, as a simple test would have shown.